# Math.evaluate is not a function

Tags: javascript, math, mathjs

im trying to do some Math in a js function while using MathJs & getting this error :Math.evaluate is not a function

```
<script src=" https://cdnjs.com/libraries/mathjs"></script>
Do-Math :<input id="formula" />
<button onclick="goCalc()">Go</button>
results:<input id="resTxt"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goCalc() {
        let  Mformula = $("#formula").val();//the formula im trying to get =6*4+2^2
        var res = document.getElementById("resTxt");
       // res.setAttribute("value", Mformula);
        var mat = Math.evaluate(Mformula);
        res.setAttribute(mat);
        console.log(mat);
        }
```

Comment: `Math.evaluate` -> `math.evaluate`

Comment: var mat = math.evaluate(Mformula); =Uncaught ReferenceError: math is not defined

Comment: Linking to the CDN page which *lists different sources* for the library, does not actually *load* the library. Pick a URL which has the library code and use that.

Comment: yes, that was the problem.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be experiencing multiple problems based on the code you've shown. It's not exactly clear which are true issues and which might be related to typos, etc. so here's a complete example demonstrating how to include the library as well as evaluating the text value of an input element each time it changes, writing the result to another element:

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; } #expression, #result { font-family: monospace; font-size: 1rem; } #expression { padding: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<label>Expression: <input id="expression" value="6 * 4 + 2 ^ 2" /></label>
<pre><code id="result"></code></pre>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/11.0.1/math.min.js" integrity="sha512-B82WLflI1EQiR9sGbIV1ddGVvK4ghj1xjMShL7YvcOrHjX2qP72lHztT1DxBVPiz1aTR6mOUJbtwj06uadL2GA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script type="module">
  const input = document.getElementById('expression');
  const output = document.getElementById('result');

  function evaluate () {
    const expression = input.value.trim();
    let result;

    try {
      result = math.evaluate(expression);
    }
    catch (ex) {
      if (ex instanceof Error) result = ex.toString();
      else throw ex;
    }

    output.textContent = result;
  }

  input.addEventListener('input', evaluate);
  evaluate();
</script>
```